# How to add <base target="..."> when using tmpl=component

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdocument

I am planning to use tmpl=component within the URL for some pages on my site to enable them to be embedded in iframes conveniently and only show the document content.

However, I want any links within those pages to forcibly load in the parent frame. Consequently, I need to add the following element into the head of the pages in question.

```
<base target="_parent">
```

I don't see a method on JDocument that will allow me to inject this off-hand though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I also had to show component output in an iframe on another domain. I ended up creating a very simple template showing only the component output. I added the base target line in the template's header. Then instead of tmpl=component I used tmpl=simpletemplatename.